# What different between task_reject_on_worker_lost and task_acks_late in Celery

Tags: python, task, celery

Can you explain what do I have to use: `task_reject_on_worker_lost` or `task_acks_late` and how they are different? 
Why Celery don't run task again after exception when task_acks_late is True?

In Celery docs:

> Even if task_acks_late is enabled, the worker will acknowledge tasks when the worker process executing them abruptly exits

What does it mean "abruptly exits"? Will an exception be raised?

When Celery retries task when `task_acks_late` is `True` and when `task_reject_on_worker_lost` is `True`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want it to retry after an exception you can pass args to the decorator.

```
@app.task(max_retries=10)
def task(*args, **kwargs):
    #stuff
```

Abruptly exits refers to the worker being killed not an exception. If you use `task_acks_late` then the worker will remove the item from the queue at the end of the task rather than the beginning. However, if the worker process is killed the task is still acknowledged even if it wasn't completed. `task_reject_on_worker_lost` will re-queue the message if the above event happens so you won't lose the task.

Sources:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-task_reject_on_worker_lost

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#task-acks-late

You should be able to use both of these settings together with no issues.

Comment: "If you use task_acks_late then the worker will remove the item from the queue at the end of the task rather than the beginning. However, if the worker process is killed the task is still acknowledged even if it wasn't completed"

I don't think this is correct. From the docs:
https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/faq.html#faq-acks-late-vs-retry

"The acks_late setting would be used when you need the task to be executed again if the worker (for some reason) crashes mid-execution"

So if the worker process is killed, the task is NOT acknowledged

Comment: Task reject on worker lost setting has specified this in the docs https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#task-reject-on-worker-lost  "Even if task_acks_late is enabled, the worker will acknowledge tasks when the worker process executing them abruptly exits or is signaled (e.g., KILL/INT, etc)."